# How to activate taskpane plugin/addin for office online when i open a excel file.[Office Addin]

Tags: office-js, office-2016

I have created the custom addins for office 2016, and its online version. AddIns for office 2016, provide the option to add the ribbon bar button and when you click on it, a taskpane is shown.

If i dont use the ribbon bar element in manifest file of addin and if i close my excel file with taskpane open and then again open the same excel file, i see that taskpane is showing but if i have ribbon button for showing my taskpane, and if i do same action like closing and saving the excel file and again open it, task pane is not displayed. i need to manually click on that file.

i am searching for option when i open my excel file it should automatically do the action of showing the taskpane.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add ribbon buttons (or right-click menu buttons), then it's currently not possible to trigger task-pane-open when the document is opened.

Thank you for the suggestion; we'll consider adding this feature in the future.

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)

Comment: thanks for your reply. i consider this as answer as its coming from PM of office add-ins

Comment: hi Michael, i have raised another question about the addin can you please reply to that also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714959/how-to-automate-automatics-addition-of-office-plugin-in-excel-file-basically-sim

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now available. You can configure the file to autoopen a task pane. For details, see [Automatically open a task pane with a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document).