# how to automate automatics addition of Office Plugin in excel file basically similar XLSTART folder work. Office Addin

Tags: office365, office365api, office-js

I am looking for option to automatically add my addins to users excel file. before 2013 office we had a xla and xlam file which i could place in **XLSTART folder of office excel** and then when i open office, it will prompt me to include addins in excel file if its not trusted or automatically included it if its already from trusted source.

My office addin is not released to office store, it will be in user organization catalog.

Basically my workflow would be -> when i click on export to excel button in my web application, it should start online excel file (user would need to provide credential for office portal, i dont think this can be automated), and then my addins should get activated, and should do some default activity.

i dont want user to manually insert the addins if its not available in his catalog. it should automatically insert.

what is the best approach for this.

i am planning to copy my excel file template in users one drive then planning to open that every time user click export to excel..but for that to work addins manifest file should be present in users catlog.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Group Policy info on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219429.aspx?

Comment: thanks for reply, all i found is that user need to manually insert the addins in office document.

Comment: Which of the two problems are you trying to solve:  a) ensuring that the corporate catalog gets pushed to all users, or  b) getting the add-in to automatically/easily insert into the document?

Comment: In that case, does the link above solve the first problem?  And does your template method ("copy my excel file template in users one drive") solve the second?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you can have a blank template Excel file with your add-in already. You use this file to export your data in, save it under a different name, and then send it to the user to open. In this case, if the template file already has your add-in, it will go to the new file too.