# Microsoft Excel AddIn-how to know if its already installed. office.js

Tags: office365-apps, office-js

i am developing an office excel addins using office.js. i am going to copy my excel file to users one drive location and open it. as my addin doesnt have ribbon button it will open my addin when my excel file is opened([How to activate taskpane plugin/addin for office online when i open a excel file.[Office Addin]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714464/how-to-activate-taskpane-plugin-addin-for-office-online-when-i-open-a-excel-file)).

before i copy my excel file to users one drive location, i want to know if user has already installed office addin from office store or in his organization catalog. so that i can prompt to show the link to install my addins

is it possible to know if excel file or office 365 user has office addin installed ?

Comment: Complete wild guess as I don't know Office-JS but as no answers so far  so might help :) Can't you check the file exists? E.g in VBA use the FSO.FileExists or in C# use File.Exists etc...?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to do this.  If a user opens a document that contains an add-in that he/she doesn't have, the task pane will still open and prompt the user to trust the add-in.

See image for an example.

[image]

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, Developer on Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: thank you so much..you are Savior..i hope it will be same for addins in organization catalog

Comment: I am pretty sure it would be... though feel free to post back once you try it!

Comment: So long as the recipient of the file is within your organization it should be able to find the add-in within the catalog. If the recipients are external users you may want to use the Office Store (which is basically just the "common catalog" for Office users).